# Keep keyboard open when entry unfocus in iOS .NET Maui

Tags: c#, ios, .net, maui

I'm developing an iOS app in .NET Maui and I'm experiencing an issue where the keyboard briefly disappears when I shift focus from one entry field to the next.

By default, if you have two entry fields and press enter in one entry it will not move the focus to the next entry field. To resolve this, I'm using the Completed event to manually move focus to the appropriate field.

This works, but the issue is that in between moving to the next field the keyboard hides and then reappears. This looks janky and interrupts the flow of the app.

Is there a way to keep the keyboard open?

Xaml

```
<Entry x:Name="entryOne" Completed="Entry_Completed"/>
<Entry x:Name="entryTwo" Completed="Entry_Completed"/>
```

Codebehind:

```
private async void Entry_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      //Move to next entry field
      if (sender == entryOne)
      entryTwo.Focus();
      else
      entryOne.Focus();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may change the [ReturnType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/entry?view=net-maui-8.0) property of the Entry control.

From [ReturnType Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.returntype?view=net-maui-7.0), you could set the following value for ReturnType:

**Default**, *Indicates the default style on the platform.*

**Done**, *Indicates a "Done" button.*

**Go**, *Indicates a "Go" button.*

**Next**, *Indicates a "Next" button.*

**Search**, *Indicates a "Search" button.*

**Send**, *Indicates a "Send" button.*

I recommend you use the value of **Next**. When you click the `Next` Button, the keyboard will not disappear.

```
<Entry x:Name="entryOne" Completed="Entry_Completed" ReturnType="Next"/>
<Entry x:Name="entryTwo" Completed="Entry_Completed" ReturnType="Next"/>
```

---

**Updates**

I recommend you use [SetFocusOnEntryCompletedBehavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/behaviors/set-focus-when-entry-completed-behavior) in Maui CommunityToolkit. Here is how to [Get started with it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/get-started?tabs=CommunityToolkitMaui).

With **SetFocusOnEntryCompletedBehavior**, you don't have to set focus event programmatically in code behind. Just try the following code,

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
...
         xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit">


<Entry x:Name="entryOne"
       toolkit:SetFocusOnEntryCompletedBehavior.NextElement="{x:Reference entryTwo}"
       ReturnType="Next"
       />
<Entry x:Name="entryTwo"
        toolkit:SetFocusOnEntryCompletedBehavior.NextElement="{x:Reference entryOne}"
        ReturnType="Next"/>
```

---

[image]

Hope it helps!

Comment: Setting ReturnType="Next" works on Android but not iOS. I wasn't aware of the simpler way to move to the next Entry using community tool kit though, thanks!

Comment: @OttoRocket That's weird. It should work on iOS(please see my gif). You may try my code using CommunityToolkit. By the way, if above answer is helpful, please consider accepting it as answer(click the ✔ in the upper left corner of this answer), it will help others who have similar issue. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Updating from .NET 7 to .NET 8 has solved the issue